# Display pic using image path from mysql db

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am successfully displaying pictures into a table from a mysql database though I cannot work out how to add width and height or `alt=""` to this line of code without getting an error message.

```
echo "\t<tr><td><img src=\"" .$row[pic1]. " \"> " .$row["name"]. "<br>" .$row["location"]. "</td></tr>\n<br>" ;
```

Can anyone show where the `width="200"` `height="160"` should go?

Comment: Show previous attempts and what specific error (with forgotten quote escaping?) you ran into. (Btw, XHTML is no more. It's silly to quote alphanumeric attributes.)

Comment: I presumed it should go here before the closing > 

echo "\t<tr><td>  <img src=\"" .$row[pic1]. " \" width="200" height="160"> "  .$row["name"]. " <br> " . $row["location"]. "</td></tr>\n <br>" ;

I get the error message 

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting ',' or ';' in /home/xxxx/public_html/test/aaaa.php on line 38

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want you could try:

```
echo "\t".'<tr><td><img src="' .$row['pic1']. '"
     width="200" height="160" alt=""> '
     .$row['name']. ' <br> '
     .$row['location']
     ."</td></tr>\n<br>" ;
```

or

```
echo "\t".'<tr><td><img src="' .$row['pic1']. '"
     width="' .$row['width']. '" height="' .$row['height']. '"
     alt="' .$row['alt']. '"> '
     .$row['name'].' <br> '
     .$row['location']
     ."</td></tr>\n<br>" ;
```

You should probably read about PHP string syntax and escaping at https://php.net/language.types.string

Answer (score 0):

if you have any problem why dont you change this

```
 echo "\t<tr><td>  <img src=\"" .$row[pic1]. " \"> "  .$row["name"].
         " <br> " . $row["location"]. "</td></tr>\n <br>" ;
```

to this

```
<tr><td>  <img src="<?php echo $row['pic1']?>"  width="200" height="160" alt=""><?php echo $row['name']?><br/><?php echo  $row['location']?></td></tr><br>
```

try to code simpler at-least you can understand

Comment: Or you could use short echo syntax `<?= $row['pic1'] ?>` for cleaner code if you use PHP 5.4+ (or have short_open_tag ini setting enabled).

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks so much. Worked a treat. Been reading for hours trying to work that out!

Answer (score 0):

When outputting HTML from strings, you should alternate between `"` outer quotes, and `'` for HTML attributes:

```
echo "<tr><td><img src='$row[pic1]' width=200 height=150>
      $row[name]
      <br>
      $row[location]
      </td></tr>
      <br>" ;
```

More readable. Also read up on [HEREDOC strings](https://php.net/manual/de/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc).

Now more importantly you should usually pre-escape output variables via [`htmlspecialhars()`](http://php.net/htmlspecialhars).